# Export shapefile data into Excel

Tags: shapefile, export, excel, svg

I want to find the least challenging method of getting a shapefile into Excel.

I understand this is often achieved using an .svg file (which must be converted from an .shp).

Answer (score 2):

Once you create a shp file, it creates five other extensions and one of them is the DBF extension, which you can open it in Excel.

Comment: Oh thanks. How do I take this dbf file which extracted in excel and manipulate it to develop a choropleth

Comment: In Excel you have to locate to the DBF file for that specific shp file by using Open/Browse/All Files(file type). Once you manipulate the data then you can simply load the shp file into a GIS software.

Comment: @Sam IMO unless you _really_ know what you're doing, make a copy of the DBF to use in Excel. You can potentially corrupt the attributes of your shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want it to display in excel? if youre just wanting the attribute data then you can either select all the records in the attribute table and copy them over to a new excel sheet, or you can open the DBF file for the appropriate shapefile and then edit the data that way.

Comment: I suppose that the wish is to show a map in Excel like here http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2009/08/build-your-own-choropleth-maps-with-excel.html

Comment: @user30184...fair enough...but why?